# warning: passing argument 1 of ‘pthread_join’ makes integer from pointer without a cast error

Tags: c, pthreads, posix

```
#include  pthread.h
#include stdio.h

static int seq[50];
void *runner(void *); /* the thread */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int y;
    pthread_t tid[3]; /* the thread identifier */
    pthread_attr_t attr; /* set of attributes for the thread */
    if(argc!=2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"you need to enter two arguments");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        int a = atoi(argv[1]);
        if(a>0)
        {
            y=a;
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"you need to enter a valid number greater than zero");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    /* get the default attributes */
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr,PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    /* create three threads */
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, runner,(void *)y);
    /* now wait for the thread to exit */
    sleep(2);
    printf( " Am in main process, The sequence is  ");
    int j=0,val=0;
    for( j = 0; j < 40; j++)
    {
        val=seq[j];
        if(val>=1)
            printf( "  %d  ", seq[j]);
    }
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    pthread_exit(0);
}
/**
 * The thread will begin control in this function
 */
void *runner(void *param)
{
    int count=0;
    int y= (int *) param;
    //       printf(" Am in runner");
    while(y!=1)
    {
        if(y%2==0)
            y = y/2;
        else
            y= ((3*y)+1);
        //  printf(" %d ", y);
        seq[count] = y;
        count++;

    }
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

I am getting the following errors

```
bonus.c: In function ‘main’:
bonus.c:91: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
bonus.c:91: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type
bonus.c:123: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘pthread_join’ makes integer from pointer without a cast
bonus.c: In function ‘runner’:
bonus.c:157: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
bonus.c:159: error: invalid operands to binary %
bonus.c:161: error: invalid operands to binary /
bonus.c:165: error: invalid operands to binary *
bonus.c:171: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

Comment: This `int y = (int *) param;` is evidently wrong if you don't know why, then you shouldn't be trying to write multithreaded application.

Comment: How about you actually describe your problem, and format your code (put 4 spaces in front of each line of code)

Comment: Yeah, and test-compile what you dump here, the above isn't even close. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 3):

For whatever reason, you're declaring an array of `pthread_t`:

```
pthread_t tid[3];
```

Don't do that, unless you plan on starting three threads.
You want

```
pthread_t tid;
```

Two errors stem from this:

```
pthread_create(&tid, NULL, runner,(void *)y);
(passing argument 1 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type)
```

where you pass a pointer to the array instead of a pointer to a `pthread_t`, and

```
pthread_join(tid, NULL);
(passing argument 1 of ‘pthread_join’ makes integer from pointer without a cast)
```

where you pass a pointer to a `pthread_t` instead of a `pthread_t`.

The warning

```
cast to pointer from integer of different size
```

comes from `(void*) y` — an `int` is smaller than a `void*` if you're compiling for a 64-bit target.
You should use `&y` or give `y` a type that is as large as a `void*`, such as `int64_t`.

In `runner` you're casting the parameter to `int*`, which is very odd since it started out as an `int`.
You need to make sure that you cast back to the same type you started with.
You then proceed to initialise an `int` with this value, but that can't be your actual code because the following errors are consistent with

```
int* y = (int *) param;
```

so I suspect you lost a "*" when entering the code in the question.

If you pass a pointer to `int` in the parameter, that should be

```
int y = *(int*) param;
```

if you pass an integer reinterpreted as a pointer, it should be

```
int64_t y = (int64_t) param;
```

if you settle on `int64_t` as your integral type.

Also, keep in mind that printing the elements of an array while a thread is modifying them is possibly not the best of ideas, and neither is not ensuring that the thread doesn't overstep the array boundaries.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Dang. I thought I caught'em all.

Answer (score -1):

```
pthread_create(&tid, NULL, runner,(void *)y);
```

==>

```
for( i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, runner,(void *)y);
}
```

and

```
pthread_join(tid, NULL);
```

==>

```
for( i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
}
```

Comment: Even though this is correct, it's one of the worse answers I've seen, because you explained absolutely nothing.

Comment: @iharob, i think the person who was able to create such a code knows at least basics of the language . this means this is a typo or "logical glitch" and really should not be on the stack overflow.

Comment: Then don't answer it. And this person wrote code with very many fundamental mistakes that indicate a lack of knowledge about the programming language, check the code please.

Comment: @fukanchik: Very dangerous assumption to make. At least state disclaimers in the answer, in the form of actual disclaimers or y'know an explanation or something